# skip committing path in the scripts

Tags: git, github, path, gitignore

I'm looking for a git code that allows me to avoid committing the paths in the script. I switch between Mac and PC often to process data that are saved locally, because they use different directories, it's annoying that I need to change the path if I switch the system. I tried to use

```
git rm -r --cached <dir>
```

But the paths are still being committed. Or should I use `gitignore` in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean paths within a script file?

Comment: @VonC yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I use a template for .gitignore for mac:

```
# General
*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

you can find a lot of useful templates here:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/macOS.gitignore